# Text vertically aligned in tables

Tags: tables

I have create a table using a online creator,and I have no idea how to setthe text vertically centered. I have red all the post I have found about this topic. However, since I didn´t  make my code and I am new in Latex Idont find any answer. Below I provide the code and the table, I would like to have all the text vertically centered. Which change could I do?

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lclc}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Malla}}                                                                  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Dominio}}                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Parámetro}}                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Valor}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Parámetro}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Valor}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\Delta x_{min} = \Delta y_{min}$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Longitud en x}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{$\Delta x_{max} =  \Delta y_{max}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Longitud en y}      & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{nx}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Distancia A}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{ny}                                   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Distancia B}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Puntos en el cilindro}                & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1x1}            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Distancia C}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{}               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Distancia D}        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1}              \\ \hline
                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                &                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                \\
                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                &                                         & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}                                           
\end{tabular}
\caption{Datos de la malla y el dominio para el problema del cilindro}
\end{table}
```

[image: table]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Replace  `\begin{tabular}{lclc}`  with `\begin{tabular}{cccc}`. However there could be some improvements to do.

Comment: why have you got every cell in a `\multicolumn` ??

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As i said, I dont understand the code, I just used tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: @Bernard Im sorry to say, it didnt work

Comment: Everywhere you have `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}`, you need `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}` or you could just delete all occurrences of `\multicolumn{1}{|l|}` in addition to @Bernard's suggestion.

Comment: I can't see the point in using a generator to generate code that is vastly more complicated than needed (none of those `\multicolumn` commands do anything useful, it would be simpler really just to hand write the table markup, which is not any more complicated than normal latex text,  you just need a `&` to separate cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version with some improvements, using mathmode except for one column:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array, amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}\setlength\abovecaptionskip{20pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{2}{>{$}c<{$}|}c|>{$}c<{$}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Malla}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Dominio}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Parámetro} & \textbf{Valor} & \textbf{Parámetro} & \textbf{Valor} \\
    \hline
    \Delta x_{\min} = \Delta y_{\min} & 1 & Longitud en $x$ & 1 \\
    \hline
    \Delta x_{\max} = \Delta y_{\max} & 1 & Longitud en $y$ & 1 \\
    \hline
    nx & 1 & Distancia A & 1 \\
    \hline
    ny & 1 & Distancia B & 1 \\
    \hline
    \text{Puntos en el cilindro} & 1\times1 & Distancia C & 1 \\
    \hline
                                      & & Distancia D & 1 \\
    \hline%
    %& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
    %& \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & & \multicolumn{1}{l}{}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Datos de la malla y el dominio para el problema del cilindro}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very basic clean up which centres the text. It does not, however, try to improve the typesetting of the table beyond that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Malla}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Dominio}}                                         \\ \hline
{\textbf{Parámetro}}                   & {\textbf{Valor}} & {\textbf{Parámetro}} & {\textbf{Valor}} \\ \hline
{$\Delta x_{min} = \Delta y_{min}$}  & {1}              & {Longitud en x}      & {1}              \\ \hline
{$\Delta x_{max} =  \Delta y_{max}$} & {1}              & {Longitud en y}      & {1}              \\ \hline
{nx}                                   & {1}              & {Distancia A}        & {1}              \\ \hline
{ny}                                   & {1}              & {Distancia B}        & {1}              \\ \hline
{Puntos en el cilindro}                & {1x1}            & {Distancia C}        & {1}              \\ \hline
{}                                     & {}               & {Distancia D}        & {1}              \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Datos de la malla y el dominio para el problema del cilindro}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: basic clean up]

For a higher-quality result, you might start by reading the **booktabs** guidelines and trying something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Malla}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dominio}}                                         \\\cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    {\textbf{Parámetro}}                   & {\textbf{Valor}} & {\textbf{Parámetro}} & {\textbf{Valor}} \\\midrule
    {$\Delta x_{min} = \Delta y_{min}$}  & {1}              & {Longitud en x}      & {1}              \\
    {$\Delta x_{max} =  \Delta y_{max}$} & {1}              & {Longitud en y}      & {1}              \\
    {nx}                                   & {1}              & {Distancia A}        & {1}              \\
    {ny}                                   & {1}              & {Distancia B}        & {1}              \\
    {Puntos en el cilindro}                & {1x1}            & {Distancia C}        & {1}              \\
    {}                                     & {}               & {Distancia D}        & {1}              \\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Datos de la malla y el dominio para el problema del cilindro}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: improved version]

Comment: In the first example I see it as before, the second however is prettynice, thanks! I will read that documentation to improve my abilities

Comment: I may have misread the question. You had some cells centred and some not and I thought you wanted them all centred in the same way. But now I think that may not be what you meant.

Comment: Dont worry, I will use bookstabs, is cleaner and more stetic

Comment: @cfr, Good answer! I see that I urgently need a course for fast typing ... you were faster than me (for 3 minutes) again :-).

Comment: @Zarko Maybe you took the time to read the question ;).

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear what you mind with "vertical centered". Your example is vertically perfectly centered, as far as I see. Only if you like to have in last two rows vertically centered `Puntos en el cilindro`?

Another problem is, how you write your table. See, if the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
\section{Some section}

    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{lclc}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Malla}}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Dominio}}   \\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-4}
\textbf{Parámetro}  
    &   \textbf{Valor} 
        &   \textbf{Parámetro} 
            &   \textbf{Valor}          \\ 
    \midrule
$\Delta x_{min} = \Delta y_{min}$  
    & 1 &   Longitud en x       &   1   \\ 
$\Delta x_{max} =  \Delta y_{max}$ 
    & 1 &   Longitud en y       &   1   \\ 
nx  & 1 &   Distancia A         &   1   \\ 
ny  & 1 &   Distancia           &   1   \\
Puntos en el cilindro
    & 1x1   & Distancia C       &   1   \\
    &   &   Distancia D         &   1   \\ 

    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Datos de la malla y el dominio para el problema del cilindro}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

It gives:

[image]

As you see, in code I omit all `multicolumn`s except the first two, which are necessary. I also use `booktabs` package for drawing horizontal lines.

In above code I also omit bunch of `multicolumn`s without text. I didn't figured out their purpose, so I decided to not considered them.

Comment: Your table is awesome, Im considering to use it, with your permission. With vertically centered I mean that the text is not at the same distance from the top of the cell than from the bottom. However with your answer, it doesn´t matter. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need any permission to use any code published on SE ... (for personally use) ... but as I see from fact, which answer you accept, your taste is so different from mine, that this will not happen :-)

Comment: I don't think you need permission for impersonal use, either. Attribution is required, but the cc licence thing is pretty permissive. (And, if SE has its way, attribution may not be required for much longer either. At least, not unless somebody retrospectively requests it or SE retrospectively requests it.) But I'm not a lawyer and this does not constitute legal advice!

Comment: I like this table the best.